# Correct way of modifying list/objs in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, setstate

I have a code snippet below which I am not very sure if it is done correctly.

Here is my code block:

```
onChangeMethod(event) {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        list: [...prevState.list, event.value]
    }));
}
```

I have seen another example [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) and I adapted my code here. Can it be done this way? Meaning, can I take the value of event passed to the `onChangeMethod()` and use it directly in the function declared in the `setState()`?

```
onChangeMethod(event) {
    this.setState((state, event.value) => ({
        list: state.list.push(event.value)
    }));
}
```

Cheers community

Comment: Your first snippet it fine, except that you should extract the `value` from the event target since the function given to `setState` will be invoked asynchronously. `const { value } = event.target; this.setState(prevState => ({ list: [...prevState.list, value] }));`

Comment: First one is the recommended one. I always like the first one

Comment: Can someone tell me how prevState comes about? Do i need to declare it anywhere?

Comment: @AKJ The argument given to `setState` is a function, and the first argument of that function is the previous state. In your code you name that argument `prevState`, but you could name it whatever you see fit, e.g. `previousState` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code
`prevState => ({list: [...prevState.list, event.value]})`
is an anonymous arrow function with a parameter named `prevState` returning an object `{list: [...prevState.list, event.value]}`. You are passing this function to another function `setState` as an argument.
`setState` function later on calls your function providing the current components state as the first argument (actually it will call your function with 2 parameters: prevState and props).

smth like:
`function setState(callback) { callback(component.state, component.props) }`

Your second code snippet is just incorrect in 2 ways:

1. It has incorrect syntax - you cannot call a variable (parameter) `event.value`.
2. `setState` will pass component props as the second argument and not an event

I strongly suggest you read more about functions, arrow function, callbacks, closure and javascript in general.

To answer your question, your first code sample is the way to go, you already have variable event in the anonymous arrow function context and will work fine.

Comment: @AKJ Your are welcome. Don't forget to accept someone's answer (if you think it answers your question) or create your own answer if you find it yourself and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is YES but first I need to correct some things in your code.
When dealing with an array property in your state object, you should never modify state directly by the use of array methods like `push()`. For your use case you can do the following:

```
onChangeMethod({ target: { value } }) {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
        list: [ ...prevState.list, value ]
    }));
}
```

Or you can use the `concat()` method which always returns a new array like so:

```
onChangeMethod({ target: { value } }) {
    this.setState({
        list: this.state.list.concat(value)
    });
}
```